# iptables fails to load nf_conntrack_ftp

Tags: iptables, nf-conntrack

I have recently had to rebuild my iptables configuration and when I run

```
service iptables restart
```

I now receive the following error line:

```
iptables: Loading additional modules: nf_conntrack_ftp   [FAILED]
```

My iptables-config file includes the following line:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp"
```

When I run modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp the response is:

```
FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ftp not found.
```

Here's my iptables file:

> Table: mangle Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot
> opt source               destination
>
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot opt source
> destination 1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> state NEW tcp dpt:8447 2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0
> 0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8443
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot opt source
> destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot opt source
> destination
>
> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot opt source
> destination
>
> Table: filter Chain INPUT (policy DROP) num  target     prot opt
> source               destination 1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0
> 0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 2    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00 3    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02
> state NEW 4    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F 5    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0
> 0.0.0.0/0 6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:443 8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:25 9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:995 10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:143 11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:993 12   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:22 13   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:110 14   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:465 15   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:8181 16   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
> tcp dpt:8443 17   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot opt source
> destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) num  target     prot opt source
> destination

It seems nf_conntrack_ftp isn't loading -- how do I load this?

Comment: Last time I saw something similar, it was on Ubuntu, and someone had uninstalled the current kernel package, thus removing the module from /lib/modules/<version>/.  Is this perhaps what's happened here?

Comment: Please post the output of the `virt-what` command (install it if it isn't present).

Comment: You'll need to contact your VPS provider, then.

Comment: My understanding is that nf_conntrack_ftp operates on its own without needing any iptables config. Try `lsmod | grep conntrack` to see if it's loaded; if not, find the file on your drive (it may have the `.ko` extension), change to that directory and use insmod or modprobe on that file including any extension. Check `/etc/modules-load.d/nf_conntrack_ftp.conf` for any mistakes. If the file doesn't exist, it will simply monitor port 21.

Answer (score 2):

Try issuing the following:

> modprobe ip_conntrack & modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp

Then substitute `nf_conntrack_ftp` with `ip_conntrack_ftp` in your iptables configuration.

Comment: If you would kindly delete your response, I would like to delete my question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I get the error with `ufw enable`, what can I do?